# htaccess limit access when request includes parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain

If a website is in a shared hosting space, with parent folder, and subdomains in subfolders, is it possible to limit access to subdomain when url request includes parent domain?

folder structure in share hosting space is:

domain.com
    etc
    this 
    that
    subdomaina.com

I can access subdomain a like 
    a) http://subdomaina.com 
    b) http://domain.com/subdomaina.com

How can I prevent b from happening?

I added an .htaccess file in domain.com with a 301 redirect to http://subdomaina.com, but the I get a loop like http://subdomaina.com/index.php/index.php/index.php...

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are putting sub domains in sub folders and not using virtual hosts to map domains into their own document roots (folders)?

Comment: @Michael Coleman The websites are in a shared hosting server. Not a dedicated server or a private server. I think shared hosting users have no access to server configuraiton

Comment: Do you have cpanel on your shared hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can access subdomain a like a) `http://subdomaina.com` b) `http://domain.com/subdomaina.com` How can I prevent b from happening?

You can use this code in your `subdomaina.com/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# forbid access is domain is not subdomaina.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?subdomaina\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: the second block of code you indicated works; however, if I include the first two lines of your code, I get "Internal Server Error" Thank you

Comment: This answer works patially. In shared hosting, public server, using line RewriteBase /subdomaina.com/ returns a server error. The rest of the code would be the correct answer

Comment: Yes I have corrected it now so that I can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your websites are not setup and configured properly.

> is it possible to limit access to subdomain when url request includes
>   parent domain?

Yes, under a normal `DNS`-> `webserver virtual host` -> `source files (index.html etc)` configuration - requests to the parent domain and its content is separate from subdomains.
In other words the sub domain is practically treated the same way as a completely different website.

> How can I prevent b from happening?

You need to configure your webserver to route requests to the subdomain to a separate folder on your file system. (i.e. the `document root`). 
The fact that your server is shared has no practical difference to how you configure and organise you files etc

So what you should have is

```
request for                              
subdomaina.com --->|             |--->subdomaina.com - content files
                   |             |   /home/web/subdomaina/index.html
                   |-->webhost --|
                   |   server    |     
request for ------>|             |---> domaina.com - content files
 domaina.com       |             |   /home/web/subdomaina/index.html
```

Where you webserver configuration "knows" which files are for which domain.

#### How do you set this up?

If you have a shared hosting service - usually you can just call or message tech support and ask them to help setup your subdomains.
Otherwise you can do it your self - usually through cpanel.
where you need to specify your subdomain and where the files for your subdomain are located.